# How to remove several identical items from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a method that removes several identical/duplicate items from a JavaScript array like this:

```
var array = [55, 65, 55, 65, 55, 65, 55, 65, 55, 65];
```

With this array, for example, I am trying to remove all of the duplicates of `55` and `65` so that I am only left with `[55, 65]`.

I've tried using `splice()` but that only removes by the position number, where I need something to remove all of the items of the same value.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array.

Comment: Google for "javascript array unique".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the array and use a hash table for look-up.

```js
var array = [55, 65, 55, 65, 55, 65, 55, 65, 55, 65, true, 'true'];

array = array.filter(function (a) {
    var key = typeof a + '|' + a;
    if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = true;
        return true;
    }
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(array, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This will treat `true` and `"true"` as duplicates, as well as `1` and `"1"` etc.

Comment: @torazaburo, please see edit.